# Change from web SDK to modular SDK @firebase/auth: Auth (9.23.0): INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

Having error below after changed to modular SDK implementation.
I should changed all method accordingly and there's no any import from /compat/
No error from IDE, compile with ionic serve all working fine with no error. Program run fine just angularfire doesn't works at all.

Really need hope as I did fully check all and totally no ideas what's the possible cause.

```
@firebase/auth: Auth (9.23.0): INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition after changed from web SDK implementation to modular SDK.

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition
Error: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition
    at U (index-e3d5d3f4.js:520:11)
    at j (index-e3d5d3f4.js:531:9)
    at _t (index-e3d5d3f4.js:1742:5)
    at index-e3d5d3f4.js:2663:59
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at i (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at C (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:27:1
    at new _ (zone.js:1340:25)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:19:1
    at P.invoke (zone.js:412:30)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:26321:33)
    at P.invoke (zone.js:411:56)
    at P.run (zone.js:166:47)
    at zone.js:1315:38
    at P.invokeTask (zone.js:446:35)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26308:33)
    at P.invokeTask (zone.js:445:64)
    at P.runTask (zone.js:211:51)
    at Ue (zone.js:635:39)
    at P.invokeTask (zone.js:532:25)
    at P.ne.useG.invoke (zone.js:517:52)
    at B.c.args.<computed> (zone.js:2422:36)
```

Environment
"@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
"firebase": "^9.23.0",

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 7.1.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 7.2.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 16.1.5
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 16.1.5
@angular/cli                  : 16.1.5
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 10.0.0

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI      : 5.2.2
@capacitor/android : 5.2.2
@capacitor/core    : 5.2.2
@capacitor/ios     : 5.2.2

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed globally
native-run  : 1.7.2

System:

NodeJS : v18.12.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm    : 9.8.1
OS     : macOS Unknown

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Solved by removing wrong function applied.
this.auth.setPersistence()

hopefully in the future it could trace and catch the inappropriate error more accurately.